# Tengo un problema al hacer un registro con c# y entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: al hacer un registro en un form al seleccionar un dato de un combobox]
me sale un dialogo pero no se que indica... al cargar los datos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
var listaRed = con.Registros.ToList();
            if (listaRed.Count > 0)
            {
                cbSelecNombreRed.DataSource = listaRed;
                cbSelecNombreRed.DisplayMember = "Nombre_red";
                cbSelecNombreRed.ValueMember = "ID_Registro";
                if (cbSelecNombreRed.Items.Count > 1)
                    cbSelecNombreRed.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
```

Comment: Solucionado saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre tenga cuidado al convertir valores a Int directamente, puede ocurrir este tipo de problema.

Normalmente lo hago de esta manera:

```
    var a = 2;
    if (a is int)
    {
        //is integer
    }
    //or:
    if (a.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
        //is integer
    }
```